# Creating a URL Alias or Making Deep-Urls Pretty

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have fairly deep urls with IDs and I want to see if I can convert them into something nicer looking. I tried looking into how Slugs are done for Yesod Blog (https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Slugs) but not sure if I know how to translate that to what I am looking for here.

Suppose let's say I want to display Top Fiction Books, I have a resource that looks like this:

```
/topbooks/bookcategory/#BookCategoryId
```

If I go to `/topbooks/bookcategory/1` I may get Fiction books, If I got to `/topbooks/bookcategory/2` I may get Non-fiction, etc.

All my handlers use the `#BookCategoryId` input parameter in the database queries to get the appropriate records.

Ideally I would like to create a url that looks like: `/topbooks/fiction`, `/topbooks/non-fiction`etc. If I create my route as `/topbooks/#Text`, I can pattern match the string and return a `Key` back. However, I will have to manually transform it in every handler using `#BookCategoryId`. Note that the IDs are used as Foreign keys so it makes a bit cumbersome to rely on `getBy` like how it is done in Slug example.

So I am wondering if there is a better way to do it:  Is it possible to define a custom type similar to `Slug` but instead of just converting values to/from Text / String, actually output `IDs`? That way I can just use the parameter directly in my queries.

**Update:**

To clarify given Michael's comment:

I understand we cannot get the IDs without doing a database lookup. In fact for this example, I am ok hard coding the look-up mechanism. I was just trying to see if the `PathPiece` mechanism will somehow simplify the conversion process.

For example, if something like this worked then it will be fine but of course I will get a type error since I am trying to return a Key when the compiler is expecting BookCategories.

```
 data BookCategories = FICTION | NONFICTION 

 instance PathPiece BookCategories where
    toPathPiece (FICTION)    = T.pack "fiction" 
    toPathPiece (NONFICTION) = T.pack "nonfiction"

    fromPathPiece s =
       let ups = map toUpper $ T.unpack s
       in  
        case reads ups of
         [(FICTION, "")]    -> Just $ Key $ PersistInt64 1
         [(NONFICTION, "")] -> Just $ Key $ PersistInt64 
         [] -> Nothing
         otherwise -> Nothing
```

Of course I could just return `Just FICTION` and unwrap it in my handler. This is not conceptually very different from actually pattern matching on Text directly with a function with a signature `Text -> BookCategoryId`.

```
getBookCategoryR :: BookCategoryId -> Handler Html
getBookCategoryR bcId = do
     -- Normal use case when IDs are used in the URL
     books <- runDB $ selectList [ModelBookCategory ==. bcId] []
```

If I swtich to Text input

```
getBookCategoryR :: Text -> Handler Html
getBookCategoryR bc = do
     bcId = convertToId (bc) -- This is the line I am trying to avoid everywhere 
     books <- runDB $ selectList [ModelBookCategory ==. bcId] []
```

The one line conversion code is what I am trying to avoid. `PathPiece` has been handling it nicely for id-based-urls and kept the code clean. If there was a way to get Ids returned through some Type magic then it will be great. With limited knowledge of Haskell, I have no idea if it is even feasible.

Hope my question is clearer now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such way to do that, and the reason is simple: without consulting the database, there's no way to know if `foo` exists as a slug at all and, if it does, which ID it relates to. You'll always have to perform some database action to convert a slug into an ID.

---

**UPDATE** I'm still not certain I understand what you're looking for, but the short answer regarding PathPiece is that it only works on *pure* conversions, nothing which has side effects. If you're looking to write a function like `Text -> Handler BookCategoryId`, you can certainly do so. And if you *really* wanted to, you could even abstract this with a typeclass, though I'm not sure if you'll gain anything.

This may be barking up the wrong tree, but here's a short idea that might inspire you a bit: you could creating different `newtype` wrappers for each textual slug field, and then create a typeclass to convert a textual slug field into the appropriate entity, e.g.:

```
newtype BookCatSlug = BookCatSlug Text
    deriving PathPiece

BookCategory
    slug BookCatSlug
    title Text
    ...
    UniqueBookCat slug

class Slug slug where
    type SlugEntity slug
    lookupSlug :: slug -> YesodDB App (Maybe (Entity (SlugEntity slug)))

instance Slug BookCatSlug where
    type SlugEntity BookCatSlug = BookCategory
    lookupSlug = getBy . UniqueBookCat

lookupSlug404 slug = runDB (lookupSlug slug) >>= maybe notFound return

myHandler slug = do
    Entity bookCatId bookCat <- lookupSlug404 slug
```

Something along these lines should work, but I'm not sure if the "type magic" is worthwhile, since having a helper function and manually passing in the appropriate Unique constructor would be almost as easy for the call site and result in much simpler error messages.

Comment: Thanks, @michael. I have updated my question with some clarification. I completely understand I cannot get away with the database lookup. I am trying to see if there is a way to construct convenience functions that will do the transformation in the background like how PathPiece has been doing for Id-based-urls.

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to add an example. While this is not what exactly what I was looking for, it is nevertheless very  helpful in addressing some additional questions I had about routing. After trying out a few ideas, I feel like the answer is: 'there isn't way to do it'. If it is ok with you, I will leave this answer as unaccepted so as not to confuse others. Thanks again!